# Why does this LED not light up with 1.5V connected to it?

Tags: led

[image]

I'm a beginner in this hobby, and I'm confused as to why this circuit doesn't work when I connect it to a 1.5V battery. I tried it both directions, so I don't think the problem is polarity. Would this circuit theoretically work?

Comment: What colour is the LED? Some need at least 3V before lighting up.

Comment: what is that picture supposed to show? ... why is the newspaper the primary subject of the picture?

Comment: You are obviously capable of taking a far better photo than that. You'll find that people respond FAR better to well presentd questions. A neutral back ground, good lighting and good focus help heaps. Having the object of interest as the sole subject and having it as large as possible in the frame helps muchly.

Answer (score 7):

Your circuit is underpowered - you need 2.5v-3.5 v depending on LED color.  You'll learn the voltages needed for differing LEDs pretty quickly.   When I started I used this as a [cheat sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLcGB.png).

While a multimeter can help you determine if the LED is good, I prefer to use a Cr2032 (3V) coin cell battery instead.  It's just faster than messing with my MM.  And you don't need to worry about using a resistor with it either.  I keep a couple on my work bench at all times.

Comment: Green leds don't usually have such high Vf, unless it is some high-brigthness InGaN green. But for "regular" green diodes as used in indicators, it is about the same Vf as a yellow LED. Here is a more detailed "cheat sheet": https://www.lumex.com/led-color-guide.html

Comment: Please provide a citation or a link for the graphic that you included in your answer. It is important that we give credit to the original creator of the image, and a way for the reader to investigate further.

Comment: The link is embedded in the graphic.  Just click or tap on it

Comment: Dim - thanks, that is a much better reference.  In the (one huge) batch of LEDs I bought my green ones do take 3.2 Vf as measured by my MMs.  Below that they blink.  I don't have datasheets for them so I assume the are of the high brightness category.  But on a lot of charts I've seen online 3.0-3.3 is the Vf stated.

Comment: @JJC  Welcome to the site :-) It seems you may have misunderstood what *Elliot Alderson* said. It's a [site rule](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) that you include a link in your answer back to the original source page, when you include any resource (image, text, photo etc.) copied from elsewhere. Otherwise, as explained on that linked page, you might receive downvotes (or even have your answer removed) due to plagiarism. So, please, add a link to the original source of that table image (i.e. add a link to the original page you copied it from). Thanks :-)

Comment: @samgibson. Thanks - I think I have the entry correct based on reading how others were formatted in comments.  Learning curve.

Answer (score 4):

Most colors other than red and IR require more than 1.5V to light. You can try a CR2032 or CR2025 lithium button cell across the LED. That kind of battery has more voltage (about 3V) and enough internal resistance that it won't likely damage the LED.

[image]

You could also use 2 or 3 AA cells in series, but you **must** add some series resistance (try a 1K\$\Omega\$ resistor) or the LED will likely be destroyed very quickly.